# How to send money to single receiver using php?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

OK, I want to send money (simple payments) to single receiver (not mass) using php , how can i do that ?

[image]

Comment: I'm glad the picture cleared things up...

Comment: thank you. for show my picture  ^_^

Comment: exactly as the picture shows. You just want some free code or you tried anything?

Comment: What? Do you want to use some kind of payment service (like PayPal) or do you expect PHP to magically print dollar bills and send them from the "sender" to the "receiver"?

Comment: @user3656305 you need to be approved to use AdaptivePayments on PayPal's live site. If you want to test it using sandbox you will want to create an app on developer.paypal.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) which is part of the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) platform.

Comment: do you have sample code for simple pay ?

thank you

Comment: Are you working with PHP?

Comment: yes , i working on php , please tell me sample code to do that .

thank you for ans

Comment: Take a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) which includes [/samples/PayWithOptions.php](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/samples/PayWithOptions.php)